# How to add css to single navigation text?

Tags: menus, css, navigation

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I only want to edit the "ticket". in the photo I only add the CSS in the inspect.
I want it to be that size.how to put CSS in that span ?? 
I did add extra CSS class in the menu. but it only changes the colour background (the pink colour background). it did not change the text.
please help. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

what do you want to change exactly? like the first picture you shared or something else?

if you want to edit text itself you need to edit a tag inside the menu-ticket class

like this

```
.menu-ticket a {font-size:40px;}
```

Comment: thank you. it worked

Comment: can u check my answer below ... tq